# I make changes to WordPress theme file and nothing happens

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a WordPress template. In the footer, the template originally has this address:

[image]

I am trying to modify that address. In the WordPress admin section, I tried to achieve it by modifying the `options.php` file to have this:

[image]

All I did was to replace `28 JACKSON BLVD STE 1020 CHICAGO<br>IL 60604-2340` with `Calle 4 Final, Colonia La Mascota <br>San Salvador, El Salvador`. I clicked the `Update File` button and even logged out and logged in again in the WordPress admin system to confirm that the changes were applied successfully. In the admin section, I see the change to the address applied correctly but to my surprise, when refreshing the website, I still see the old `CHICAGO IL` address, not the new `San Salvador, El Salvador` address I want to have.

I was reading https://wordpress.org/support/article/i-make-changes-and-nothing-happens/#server-side-caching to try to figure out if this may be a server-side caching issue. I already tried loading the site from different web browsers and even visiting the website in incognito mode. I always see the old address. Any ideas? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

Answering to `cabrerahector`'s comment, this is an email I received from the hosting company:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reaching out to support. Some of our servers do continue
>   Nginx, which does perform caching. However to be able to confirm
>   whether or not your server is one of these servers, I would need you
>   to verify the account. This is for the safety and security of your
>   account. Can you please verify the last 4 digits of the Credit Card on
>   the account or your Full AMP (Account Management Panel) Password?
>   Additionally you may verify with the Customer or Developer Passphrase
>   set up in your AMP. For additional methods of authentication please
>   see the following guide.
>
> How to Verify Your Account for Support -
>   https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/help/how-to-verify
>
> Please let us know if you have any further questions; we are more than
>   happy to help.
>
> Best Regards, David W.
>
> InMotion Hosting 888-321-HOST (4678) Available 24/7
>   https://www.inmotionhosting.com

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin? Is OPcache enabled on your server?

Comment: @cabrerahector See my `UPDATE 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted technical support to receive assistance from the company that created the template and sold it to me and they explained that I could change the address here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i hope this will help you with ur issue

https://sivehost.com/index.php/knowledgebase/133/How-to-Install-WordPress-Themes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the footer of your WP theme, you can edit the file called `footer.php`, which is inside the wp-content > themes > *name_of_your_theme* folders.